# Caption above figure using knitr

Tags: captions, knitr

This is a question originally asked on stackoverflow, but it seems to receive no attention and answers there. Since it's related to LaTeX, I'm posting it also here hoping to receive some hints.

I would like to place the caption above the figure using knitr in Texmaker.
[I know that this question has already been asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22335542/knitr-figure-captions-above), and I understand that the solution suggested so far is to use:

```
\begin{figure} 
\caption{This is a caption above the figure} 
<<a-plot, echo=FALSE>>= 
plot(1) 
@ 
\end{figure}
```

But in this way I cannot show the code (given `echo=FALSE`), while I would like to show the code for R *and* the graph plotted with that R codes, with the caption above the graph.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a kludge but accomplished what you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents,fancyvrb}
\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents*}{test190893a.Rnw}
#<<a-plot, echo=FALSE,out.width='3in'>>=
#plot(1)
#@
\end{filecontents*}

\VerbatimInput[gobble=1]{test190893a.Rnw}

\textbf{This is a caption above the figure}

\begin{flushleft}
<<a-plot, echo=FALSE,out.width='3in'>>= 
plot(1) 
@
\end{flushleft} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `fig.show='hide'`

```
<<a-plot, echo=TRUE, fig.show='hide'>>= 
plot(1) 
@ 

\begin{figure} 
\caption{This is a caption above the figure} 
\includegraphics{figure/a-plot-1} 
\end{figure}
```

N.B. the figure name has suffix `-1`.